# SAPUI5 table objectStatus

Tags: sapui5

I got a table with different vehicles. Now my task is to add a (red) label to every vehicle that has no vehicle number. I know how to check for the number, but is there a way to do such a label inside a table?

I know for lists there isn't an objectStatus control with first and second status.

I got the objectStatus control working, but without first and second status it really doesn't look that good because I cant only color the text, not the label. Adding a label in front of the vehicle name makes the column really big, too.

Is there a better way for my problem? Or is it possible to use first and second status in tables too and I just did it wrong?

Comment: Would be nice if you could upload a screenshot / mockups (with annotations) of what you're trying to achieve *and* the current view in code

Comment: Also, what kind of table are we talking about? sap.m.Table or sap.ui.table.Table?